# Errors with every package/program installation Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, maya, apt-get

This problem occur after I try to use the script to install Maya 2014 and because I failed with some libraries, I used synaptic package manager to completely remove Maya and I used

```
sudo rm -r /usr/autodesk
```

After that I used Terminal to install Skype and get this error message

```
Setting up composite-2014 (2014.0-862716) ...
python: can't open file '/usr/autodesk/Composite_2014/etc/configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing composite-2014 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 composite-201400
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I will now install Wine and put the whole process and it will be more clear where the error occur.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/rrDYJhxw)'s the installation process

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 composite-2014
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Why do you tagged python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this commands:

```
apt-get install -f
dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

maybe helps

Answer (score 0):

If the last answer don't work as well (like it happens to me .. and its rear)

Just "Fake" /usr/autodesk/Composite_2014/etc/configure.py
Open the Terminal (ctl+alt+t)

```
sudo nautilus
```

Browse to /usr/autodesk and create Composite_2014/etc/configure.py (one by one)

good luck